# Create new table based on php array field

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of fields that came from a DB query.

I would like to find the best solution to create multiple tables based on unique values from a field $office_id.

So basically, I have tried using a foreach loop, store the office_id and check each time around the loop if it is unique or not, then close the last table html, start a new table html etc.

I hate this solution because it means the array must be ordered by office_id and it is quite ugly.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this using cleaner, smarter code. Do I need to do some sort of transformation on the array? Is there a better way to pull out the unique office_id field?

I also want to use the office_id as a header for each table, so that the output looks similar to the following:

```
office_id One
-----------------------------------
settle |  price |  Lister |  date  
-----------------------------------
       |        |         |

office_id Two
-----------------------------------
settle |  price |  Lister |  date  
-----------------------------------
       |        |         |
```

This is what I have (ugly), and as I type, I realise I'm missing the close  tag:

```
<?php $thisOffice = ""; ?>  
<?php foreach ($fees as $fee): ?>
<?php if($thisOffice !== $fee->office_id) : ?>  
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
<tr>
<th>Settlement</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Lister</th>
<th>Sold</th>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
<tr>
    <td> <?= $fee->settle_date ?></td>
    <td> <?= $fee->office_id ?></td>
    <td> <?= $fee->price ?></td>
    <td> <?= $fee->lister ?></td>
    <td> <?= $fee->sale_date ?></td>
</tr>
<?php $thisOffice = $fee->office_id; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Show the code you have currently.

Comment: didn't want to show how ugly it is, but done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will make your life much easier if you split the array into three dimensions:

```
$offices[$id][] = $fee;
```

This way you can use:

```
foreach ($offices as $id => $office) {
    foreach ($office as $fee) {
        // Build table
    }
}
```